# Change default text encoding in EditPad

Tags: text-editors, character-encoding, utf-8

How can I set UTF-8 as default characters encoding for new files in [EditPad](http://www.editpadlite.com/unicode.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In EditPad lite 7 I think you can only do this for each defined file type and for all undefined types:

1. Click **Options > Configure File Types**
2. Click the particular file type, or **Unspecified file type** (all other types)
3. Click the **Encoding** tab, and then set **Default Text Encoding** to *UTF-8*

Comment: This only changes the file in memory. The editpad help says "To make sure other people can read files you've written in EditPad, simply save it in an encoding that the other person can read.". However, after you do the above steps there are no changes to save the file.